# How to add prototype property to existing object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object, frontend

I have few objects in array and I want to add some props from factory to object with type - date.

I don't need to remove old values from this object. I try to do it in this way:

```
  angular.forEach($scope.things, function(item) {
    if(item.type === 'date') {
      item = DateFactory.prototype.createFactory();
    }
  })
```

but it doesn't work, where I'm wrong?
 [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/sAiEHeXHrhamvamG3J7P?p=preview)

Comment: What is `createFactory`? Why are you calling a method from the prototype?

Comment: in this case, using a factory is a mistake in the first place, because this factory creates/returns classes *(not instances of a class)*. To be more precise: a new incarnation of the same static/unchanged class, every time this factory is called. What you probably want to do in your code-example is sth. more like `$scope.things = $scope.things.map(item => item.type === 'date'? Object.assign(new DateClass(), item): item)` But to make this work, you have to change your code to provide you with the `DateClass` instead of a factory that creates a new date-class every time called.

Comment: and the method `DateFactory.prototype.createFactory()` makes no sense at all; neither that it exists nor what it does.

Comment: @Thomas yes, you right, thx for explain this fo me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the `item` within the `forEach` does not mutate the item. You need to use `obj[key]` instead:

```
angular.forEach($scope.things, function(item, key, obj) {
    if(item.type === 'date') {
      obj[key] = DateFactory.prototype.createFactory();
    }
  })
```

Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lYm5KiEpBySoXMesZBQ4?p=preview)

Also, you should return the instance of your date object from the factory:

```
return new date();
```

..and then just call the method:

```
obj[key] = DateFactory.createFactory()
```

Comment: yes! it works! Ivan, could I save previous params in object? like 'name' and 'type' in example?

Comment: @YoroDiallo Of course. You can simply append all new properties to `item` or to wrap them in e.g. `item.date` like so: `obj[key].date = DateFactory.createFactory();`

Answer (score 1):

For linking of prototype use below syntax:-

```
item = Object.create(Date);
```

Comment: but how can I make it with angular factory?

Comment: You just pass DateFactory to create method. like item = Object.create(DateFactory);

Comment: Unfortunately it not works.. ` if(item.type === 'date') {
      item = Object.create(DateFactory);
    }`, object is not change